# "wp_login" action hook does not work on Elementor Login form widget. Any solution?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to add additional hidden fields to WordPress admin login form to exclude it from hubspot which is created using Elementor Pro's Login widget. I used the below hook but it does not work:

```
<?php
function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {
?>
    <label for="amex" style="display:none">AMEX</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="amex" required="" value="" id="amex">
<?php 
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe the theme/plugin doesn't apply that filter. Go check the template that creates this login form, and see what filters it applies inside, if any.